# network doesn't work after adding second interface to netplan

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 server. When I configure netplan with just my WAN address it starts up fine and I can ping out right away. However; when I add another address to my netplan file and reboot I have to run "netplan apply" before I get any connection. Does anyone have any ideas?

edit: Just discovered that even though I can not ping out on server after reboot, I can how ever ssh into it...

```
network:  
   version: 2  
   ethernets:  
     eno1:  
      renderer: networkd  
      dhcp4: no  
      dhcp6: no  
      addresses: [WAN.190/24]  
      gateway4: WAN.1  
      nameservers:  
        addresses: [24.224.127.143, 24.224.95.205]  
     enp4s0:  
      renderer: networkd  
      dhcp4: no  
      dhcp6: no  
      addresses: [172.16.1.14/20]  
      gateway4: 172.16.1.14  
      nameservers:  
         addresses: [24.224.127.143, 24.224.85.205]
```

Comment: Sounds like you have some odd configuration headaches going on, mind sharing the config?  It sounds like if you're adding a *second* address to the same port it's failing routing, or attempting to apply it on boot it doesn't like it, but we'd need to know more about what you've set up.  (My guess is routing is at play because you can't ping out from it)

Comment: edit it to show conf. Sorry, don't know how to show spaces so had to use dashes.

Comment: which of the two interfaces is your Internet connection.  You can only have one with a gateway, as that sets the default route.  I assume the WAN is the Internet one.  Remove the `gateway4` line from `enp4s0`, run `sudo netplan apply`, and see if it works.

Comment: Well that did that trick.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I wrote up an answer to summarize the comments.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is because both your networks have gateways defined, and as such the netplan configuration is a little 'confusing' and will break your default routes to the Internet.

In `netplan` configurations, doing this will have conflicting 'default' route rules for your Internet traffic.

For network traffic headed out for a specific interface (to/from the Internet, in this case `eno1`), set the `gateway4` field.  For all other network adapters, **do not define `gateway4`** (in this case, `enp4s0`).  Then, either `sudo netplan apply` or reboot the system.

This will solve the routing headaches that you've observed.